# How to take the top-k values of a tensor after a step function?

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor:

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([1.0, -0.5, -0.2, 0.6, 0.88])
```

I'm sending this tensor through some `step function` (not necessarily this one, but given some threshold the values above it are 1 and below are 0):

```
values = torch.tensor([0.0])
step_func_out = torch.heaviside(my_tensor, values)
step_func_out
>>> torch.tensor([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0])
```

I then need to take the `top-k` values based on the original tensor's values, but only those that are above the treshold. For example, if we say that `k=2` the output should be:

```
final_output = torch.tensor([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
```

if `k=4`, the output should be:

```
final_output = torch.tensor([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0])
```

since only 3 values are above the threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
my_tensor = torch.tensor([1.0, -0.5, -0.2, 0.6, 0.88])
values = torch.tensor([0.0])
step_func_out = torch.heaviside(my_tensor, values)


# Tensor for result
final_output = torch.zeros_like(step_func_out)
# Find indicies of top-k
_, inds = torch.topk(step_func_out * my_tensor, k = 4)
# Convert indicies to boolean mask
mask = torch.zeros_like(step_func_out).bool()
mask[inds] = True
# Place 1.0 in places of values which:
# 1) into top-k
# 2) satisfies the conditions of the threshold function
final_output[mask & (step_func_out == 1)] = 1
```

*Update*

In case if my_tensor is multidimensional, change above code this way:

```
...
_, inds = torch.topk((step_func_out * my_tensor).flatten(), k = 4)
inds = np.array(np.unravel_index(inds.numpy(), final_output.shape))
...
```

Comment: Works great! Is it possible to generalize it to a 2D or 3D tensor? Say, if `my_tensor = torch.tensor([[1.0, -0.5, -0.2, 0.6, 0.88], [1.0, -0.5, -0.2, 0.6, 0.88]])` ? I get `IndexError` and can't seem to find a way to do the indexing correctly

Comment: @Penguin, I think it's possible, though it depends on how you want to find `top-k`. Do you want find `top-k` in a whole tensor?

Comment: @Penguin, updated answer. This code should work with `my_tensor` having arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!! The top-k should be per subtensor, so along dim=0. So for example, if my `k = 4` and `my_tensor = torch.tensor([[1.0, -0.5, -0.2, -0.6, 0.88], [1.0, -0.5, -0.2, 0.9, 0.88]])`, the results should be `tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])`. If `k=2`, the results should be `tensor([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])`